# Changing the title property of mp3 file using java api

Tags: java

I have more than 1000 mp3 files in one of my folder "D:\songs\Innisai Malai". Now, I want to update all file's title property to its file Name and all file's album name to Innisai Malai.

How to do it using java. Is there any API available to update the title to its file name for all the files at a time without impacting the file's sound quality.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic

this library is available on GitHub.
using it you can open a mp3 file

> Mp3File mp3file = new Mp3File("xxx.mp3");

fetch its ID3v1 tag

> ID3v1 id3v1Tag = mp3file.getId3v1Tag();

and modify using

> setTitle(String)

Answer (score 6):

You need to edit [ID3 tag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3). There are several libraries, which can do it, for example: [mp3agic](https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic) or [javamusictag](http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/)

Here is an official example for mp3agic library:

```
Mp3File mp3file = new Mp3File("SomeMp3File.mp3");
ID3v1 id3v1Tag;
if (mp3file.hasId3v1Tag()) {
  id3v1Tag =  mp3file.getId3v1Tag();
} else {
  // mp3 does not have an ID3v1 tag, let's create one..
  id3v1Tag = new ID3v1Tag();
  mp3file.setId3v1Tag(id3v1Tag);
}
id3v1Tag.setTrack("5");
id3v1Tag.setArtist("An Artist");
id3v1Tag.setTitle("The Title");
id3v1Tag.setAlbum("The Album");
id3v1Tag.setYear("2001");
id3v1Tag.setGenre(12);
id3v1Tag.setComment("Some comment");
mp3file.save("MyMp3File.mp3");
```

Comment: You are welcome, don't forget to upvote if the answer was helpfull and select the right one if it is)

Comment: I tried to do that. Since I am new to stackoverflow as a user, they are not letting me to upvote. :-)